# Distributing underscore.js-based templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I need to bundle client side templates for other people to use as part of a library of Backbone components. I can not use RequireJS or any other AMD solution.

The idea I've had is to combine all the HTML templates into a isngle JS file that defines variables to contain the templates. Then someone would just have to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/templates.js"></script>
```

templates.js could look something like

```
var ns = ns || {};
ns.templates = {};
ns.templates['my-special-list'] = "<% _.each(stuff, function(model) { %><li><% print(model.get('title')); %></li><% }); %>";
```

then my views could do things like:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        if (_.isUndefined(this.template)) {
            this.template = _.template(ns.templates['my-special-list']);
        } else {
            this.template = _.template(this.template);
        }
   }

   render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template.render(this.options));
   }
}
```

This idea seems to work. Still allows people to pass in their own templates effortlessly while still letting me combine all our templates into a single HTML file at build time.

That said though, I sense complications combining all of this. For starters, every new line would need to be converted to \n, escaping characters, etc.

I can not think of another way to do it to be honest. I tried googling around and didn't see much that helps out. RequireJS just offers a nice way to load text but this doesn't help much for me.

Are there better ways to accomplish what I want or is my approach as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)? In one my projects I'm using the [JST task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst) to compile my individual templates into one file at build time. I store them each as individual HTML files and then have this in the Gruntfile.js:

```
jst: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            namespace: 'app.templates',
            processName: function(filename) {
                // simplify the template names
                filename = filename.replace('app/templates/', '');
                return filename.replace('.html', '');
            }
        },
        files: {
            "<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates.js": ["<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/{,*/}*.html", "<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/{,*/}*.html"]
        }
    }
}
```

My header template (*app/templates/inc/header.html*), for example, looks like this:

```
<h1 class='topbar-header'><%= title %></h1> <h2 class="subtitle"><%= subtitle %></h2>
```

Which is compiled by JST and made available via `app.templates['inc/header']` which is a actually a function you call (not a string) with the object containing the parameters. In the case of my header template, I would have to pass in an object with `title` and `subtitle` properties.

```
var template = app.templates['inc/header'];
var code = template({title: 'Hello', subtitle: 'World'});
this.$el.html(code);
```

Comment: We're all mavenfied. It'll be an uphill battle to use Grunt. And wro4j will force us to readapt our project as well which is also an uphill battle.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing when trying to adapt wro4j? I could help if I would understand better the problem you have. Usually wro4j doesn't require any change to project structure and really easy to extend.